# Convert HttpResponseMessage into byte array

Tags: c#, http

i have some troubles with uploading image onto a server

here's the code:

```
var uploadServer = api.Photo.GetUploadServer(123);

var c = new HttpClient();

var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("images/amogus.jpg"));
fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = "amogus.jpg"
};
formData.Add(fileContent);


var responseFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(await c.PostAsync(uploadServer.UploadUrl, formData));
```

in the first i'm getting a link to upload image there, then i'm adding image to formData and trying to send with PostAync, on this step i have trouble because PostAsync wants uploadUrl to be byte[] but it is a HttpResponseMessage. how do i convert it?

also here is error message:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'byte[]'

Comment: It is because the `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()`'s argument is byte array. But the `PostAsync()` return the `HttpResponseMessage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ReadAsStreamAsync` and then pass it to a `StreamReader` to read the string.

You are also missing various `using` blocks, and you can also stream your file directly into `ByteArrayContent`. `requestContent` appears to be unused here.

```cs
static HttpClient c = new HttpClient();  // always keeps static or you could get socket exhaustion
```

```c
using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
using (var fileContent = new StreamContent(File.Open("images/amogus.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
{
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "amogus.jpg"
    };
    formData.Add(fileContent);

    using (var response = await c.PostAsync(uploadServer.UploadUrl, formData))
    using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        var yourString = await responseStream.ReadToEndAsync();
        // do stuff with string
    }
}
```

Are you sure you want `ASCII` and not `UTF8`? If so you could shorten the whole thing to this

```c
using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
using (var fileContent = new StreamContent(File.Open("images/amogus.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
{
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "amogus.jpg"
    };
    formData.Add(fileContent);

    using (var response = await c.PostAsync(uploadServer.UploadUrl, formData))
    {
        var yourString = await response.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // do stuff with string
    }
}
```